# Replace multiple lines with sed

Tags: sed

I have in `sample.txt` the following content

```
abc
efg
hij
klm
nop
qrs
```

I have tried replacing `abc` with other text with

```
sed -i '/abc/c\This line is removed by the admin.' sample.txt
```

Output:

```
This line is removed by the admin.
efg
hij
klm
nop
qrs
```

It worked but for a single line.

But I am wondering how could I replace a given set of lines say 1 to 3 using `sed`?

Comment: Do you want to replace multiple instance of the same text (replace all matches), or just replace a bunch of lines no matter what they contain?

Comment: You want to print the message three time or one time ? after the deletion of three lines

Answer (score 0):

If you know the line numbers, you prepend them to your pattern, like so:

```
sed -i '4 s/abc/c\This line is removed by the admin./' sample.txt
```

The above will change line 4.  If you want to change ranges (say, lines 5-10), enter the start and end line numbers with a comma between:

```
sed -i '5,10 s/abc/c\This line is removed by the admin./' sample.txt
```

$ represents the last line in the file so if you wanted say, line 100 to the end:

```
sed -i '100,$ s/abc/c\This line is removed by the admin./' sample.txt
```

You may find this [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) helpful.  Look for the section on [Ranges by line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-28).

Answer (score 0):

If your only criterion is the line numbers, then you can specify them like so:

`sed -i '1,3 s/.*/This line is removed by the admin./' sample.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution if you like to try:

```
awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=3 {$0="This line is removed by the admin."}1' file
This line is removed by the admin.
This line is removed by the admin.
This line is removed by the admin.
klm
nop
qrs
```

To write it back to the file

```
awk 'NR>=1 && NR<=3 {$0="This line is removed by the admin."}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,3c\replace lines 1 to 3 with this single line' file
```

if you want to replace each line within the range use:

```
sed $'1,3{\\athis replaces the original line\nd}' file
```

or perhaps more easily:

```
sed '1,3s/.*/this replaces the original line/' file
```